Is this differential equation linear?
Assume we have (time dependent) quantities $a(t)$, $b(t)$ for which
$$\frac{d}{dt} (a(t) b(t))=0$$
In simple words: The product of $a$ and $b$ is constant over t.
The question: is this differential equation linear or non-linear?
On the one hand it is a linear DG for $H(t)$, when the dependent variable is the product:
$$H(t) = a(t)b(t) $$
$$\frac{d}{dt} H(t)=0$$
On the other hand, the equation can be written as
$$a(t)b'(t) + b(t)a'(t) = 0$$
So it its more like a system of ODE's for functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$.
Clearly, if
$$a_1(t)b_1'(t) + b_1(t)a_1'(t) = 0$$
and
$$a_2(t)b_2'(t) + b_2(t)a_2'(t) = 0$$
then in general for the sum of $a$ and $b$ doesn't satisfy
$$(a_1+a_2)(t)(b_1+b_2)'(t) + (b_1+b_2)(t) (a_1+a_2)'(t) = 0$$
So I would say the equation is non linear, since the sum of the two solutions for $a$ and $b$ doesn't fulfill the differential equation.
So how is the equation classified in terms of whether it is linear or non-linear?

The requirement that $ab$ be a constant means that there are not two independent functions $a$ and $b$. One completely determines the other. Differentiability of neither $a$ nor $b$ is required. The solutions are precisely the functions $a$ that don't vanish (and the corresponding functions $b$ are all nonzero constant multiples of their reciprocals).
EDIT: There are also other solutions where $ab\equiv 0$, and each of $a$ and $b$ are arbitrarily defined wherever the other vanishes -- again with no requirement of differentiability of either.
In other words, differentiability of $ab$ says nothing about the differentiability of $a$ or of $b$.

I understand that. But is this differential equation now linear of non-linear? is it even an DE ?
